# Word usage: validate vs verify

Tags: validation, verify

which word should I use, validate or verify when checking for errors in form fields and checking the username and password in the database? Does the word check suitable for both cases?

Comment: use any word you want as long as others can understand it.

Comment: Use simple language. "Check" would be fine for both cases. Your users wont really appreciate using "technical" words.

Comment: Yes, "check" plus more description would be clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're asking what you should name your function, you can call it whatever you want. I prefer validate, because it's more descriptive.